# cURL returns 400 error on server, but 200 on localhost

Tags: php, curl

I am doing a couple request to an Api. When I was testing on my development server on my computer everything was working great. Only now I have deployed it to my ubuntu server it doesn't work anymore. I get a 400 error when doing a Post.

This is my code for the cURL:

```
include('curl/curl.php');
include('curl/curl_response.php');
$this->curl = new \Curl();
$this->curl->follow_redirects = false;
$this->curl->user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6';
$this->curl->options["CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER"] = false;
$this->curl->options['AUTOREFERER'] = true;
$this->curl->headers = array(
    "Content-Type"=>"application/json;charset=utf-8",
    "X-API-Client-ID"=>"12D8"
);

//it's dutch. 'Gebruikersnaam' means 'username', 'Wachtwoord' means 'password' and 'IngelogBlijven' means 'StayLoggedIn'
$this->curl->post($loginUrl, json_encode(array('Gebruikersnaam' => $this->user, 'Wachtwoord' => $this->pass, "IngelogdBlijven" => true))))
```

I did not write all of this my self but got it from github, but it was outdated so fixed everything until it worked again, but yeah, it doesn't work on my server... :(

**curl.php:**

```
<?php

/**
 * A basic CURL wrapper
 *
 * See the README for documentation/examples or http://php.net/curl for more information about the libcurl extension for PHP
 *
 * @package curl
 * @author Sean Huber <shuber@huberry.com>
**/
class Curl {

    /**
     * The file to read and write cookies to for requests
     *
     * @var string
    **/
    public $cookie_file;

    /**
     * Determines whether or not requests should follow redirects
     *
     * @var boolean
    **/
    public $follow_redirects = true;

    /**
     * An associative array of headers to send along with requests
     *
     * @var array
    **/
    public $headers = array();

    /**
     * An associative array of CURLOPT options to send along with requests
     *
     * @var array
    **/
    public $options = array();

    /**
     * The referer header to send along with requests
     *
     * @var string
    **/
    public $referer;

    /**
     * The user agent to send along with requests
     *
     * @var string
    **/
    public $user_agent;

    /**
     * Stores an error string for the last request if one occurred
     *
     * @var string
     * @access protected
    **/
    protected $error = '';

    /**
     * Stores resource handle for the current CURL request
     *
     * @var resource
     * @access protected
    **/
    protected $request;

    /**
     * Initializes a Curl object
     *
     * Sets the $cookie_file to "curl_cookie.txt" in the current directory
     * Also sets the $user_agent to $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] if it exists, 'Curl/PHP '.PHP_VERSION.' (http://github.com/shuber/curl)' otherwise
    **/
    function __construct() {
        $this->cookie_file = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'curl_cookie.txt';
        $this->user_agent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : 'Curl/PHP '.PHP_VERSION.' (http://github.com/shuber/curl)';
    }

    /**
     * Makes an HTTP DELETE request to the specified $url with an optional array or string of $vars
     *
     * Returns a CurlResponse object if the request was successful, false otherwise
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param array|string $vars 
     * @return CurlResponse object
    **/
    function delete($url, $vars = array()) {
        return $this->request('DELETE', $url, $vars);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the error string of the current request if one occurred
     *
     * @return string
    **/
    function error() {
        return $this->error;
    }

    /**
     * Makes an HTTP GET request to the specified $url with an optional array or string of $vars
     *
     * Returns a CurlResponse object if the request was successful, false otherwise
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param array|string $vars 
     * @return CurlResponse
    **/
    function get($url, $vars = array()) {
        if (!empty($vars)) {
            $url .= (stripos($url, '?') !== false) ? '&' : '?';
            $url .= (is_string($vars)) ? $vars : http_build_query($vars, '', '&');
        }
        return $this->request('GET', $url);
    }

    /**
     * Makes an HTTP HEAD request to the specified $url with an optional array or string of $vars
     *
     * Returns a CurlResponse object if the request was successful, false otherwise
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param array|string $vars
     * @return CurlResponse
    **/
    function head($url, $vars = array()) {
        return $this->request('HEAD', $url, $vars);
    }

    /**
     * Makes an HTTP POST request to the specified $url with an optional array or string of $vars
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param array|string $vars 
     * @return CurlResponse|boolean
    **/
    function post($url, $vars = array()) {
        return $this->request('POST', $url, $vars);
    }

    /**
     * Makes an HTTP PUT request to the specified $url with an optional array or string of $vars
     *
     * Returns a CurlResponse object if the request was successful, false otherwise
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param array|string $vars 
     * @return CurlResponse|boolean
    **/
    function put($url, $vars = array()) {
        return $this->request('PUT', $url, $vars);
    }

    /**
     * Makes an HTTP request of the specified $method to a $url with an optional array or string of $vars
     *
     * Returns a CurlResponse object if the request was successful, false otherwise
     *
     * @param string $method
     * @param string $url
     * @param array|string $vars
     * @return CurlResponse|boolean
    **/
    function request($method, $url, $vars = array()) {
        $this->error = '';
        $this->request = curl_init();
        if (is_array($vars)) $vars = http_build_query($vars, '', '&');

        $this->set_request_method($method);
        $this->set_request_options($url, $vars);
        $this->set_request_headers();

        $response = curl_exec($this->request);

        if ($response) {
            $response = new CurlResponse($response);
        } else {
            $this->error = curl_errno($this->request).' - '.curl_error($this->request);
        }

        curl_close($this->request);

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Formats and adds custom headers to the current request
     *
     * @return void
     * @access protected
    **/
    protected function set_request_headers() {
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($this->headers as $key => $value) {
            $headers[] = $key.': '.$value;
        }
        curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    /**
     * Set the associated CURL options for a request method
     *
     * @param string $method
     * @return void
     * @access protected
    **/
    protected function set_request_method($method) {
        switch (strtoupper($method)) {
            case 'HEAD':
                curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
                break;
            case 'GET':
                curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
                break;
            case 'POST':
                curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                break;
            default:
                curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the CURLOPT options for the current request
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param string $vars
     * @return void
     * @access protected
    **/
    protected function set_request_options($url, $vars) {
        curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        if (!empty($vars)) curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);

        # Set some default CURL options
        curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent);
        if ($this->cookie_file) {
            curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
            curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file);
        }
        if ($this->follow_redirects) curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        if ($this->referer) curl_setopt($this->request, CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->referer);

        # Set any custom CURL options
        foreach ($this->options as $option => $value) {
            curl_setopt($this->request, constant('CURLOPT_'.str_replace('CURLOPT_', '', strtoupper($option))), $value);
        }
    }

}
```

**curl_response:**

```
<?php

/**
 * Parses the response from a Curl request into an object containing
 * the response body and an associative array of headers
 *
 * @package curl
 * @author Sean Huber <shuber@huberry.com>
**/
class CurlResponse {

    /**
     * The body of the response without the headers block
     *
     * @var string
    **/
    public $body = '';

    /**
     * An associative array containing the response's headers
     *
     * @var array
    **/
    public $headers = array();

    /**
     * Accepts the result of a curl request as a string
     *
     * <code>
     * $response = new CurlResponse(curl_exec($curl_handle));
     * echo $response->body;
     * echo $response->headers['Status'];
     * </code>
     *
     * @param string $response
    **/
    function __construct($response) {
        # Headers regex
        $pattern = '#HTTP/\d\.\d.*?$.*?\r\n\r\n#ims';

        # Extract headers from response
        preg_match_all($pattern, $response, $matches);
        $headers_string = array_pop($matches[0]);
        $headers = explode("\r\n", str_replace("\r\n\r\n", '', $headers_string));

        # Remove headers from the response body
        $this->body = str_replace($headers_string, '', $response);

        # Extract the version and status from the first header
        $version_and_status = array_shift($headers);
        preg_match('#HTTP/(\d\.\d)\s(\d\d\d)\s(.*)#', $version_and_status, $matches);
        $this->headers['Http-Version'] = $matches[1];
        $this->headers['Status-Code'] = $matches[2];
        $this->headers['Status'] = $matches[2].' '.$matches[3];

        # Convert headers into an associative array
        foreach ($headers as $header) {
            preg_match('#(.*?)\:\s(.*)#', $header, $matches);
            $this->headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the response body
     *
     * <code>
     * $curl = new Curl;
     * $response = $curl->get('google.com');
     * echo $response;  # => echo $response->body;
     * </code>
     *
     * @return string
    **/
    function __toString() {
        return $this->body;
    }

}
```

So my question is:

How do I fix this problem so I don't get the 400 error on my server

Comment: An HTTP 400 code means that the remote server didn't understand your request. Usually in your scenario (works in dev, breaks in prod), it usually means some variables or values changed as an expected part of the deployment of the script (e.g. in dev you were pointing to a remote test server and now you want to point to a new URL for the prod server, or use different credentials, etc...). I'd suggest using a proxy like Fiddler to capture the request on both servers and compare the requests side-by-side. You'll probably find the culprit in the differences.

Comment: Well, the api isn't mine. I use the smae credentials. The only difference is that when I run it on localhost it works, but when I run it on my ubuntu server it fails. Nothing changed. The only difference between my localhost and server is that the server has SSL encryption.

Comment: Correction: Not smae, but same...

Comment: Again, use a proxy like Fiddler to record the exact contents of both requests and compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
It was just a stupid permissions issue...

Comment: can you share the solution for this issue, I am having the same problem with you which I couldn't be able to solve.